# Turn this cluster of if statements into somthing clearner

Tags: python, python-2.7

Well im trying to figure out how i can shorten my little cluster of if statements into something a lot shorter.

Here is a smaller version of what I am trying to do.

```
import sys

v1 = "1"
v2 = "2"


if sys.argv[1] == "any" and sys.argv[2] == "any":
        print "nofliter"

elif sys.argv[1] == v1 and sys.argv[2] == v2:
        print "filtering both"

elif sys.argv[1] == v1 and sys.argv[2] == 'any':
        print "filtering half"
```

Its pretty confusing. But i hope someone gets the just of what im trying to do by reading that. so far i only have it setup with 2 variables, but when I am done I will probably set it up with over 8.

Basically if something is not defined then anything is okay.

example:

```
if varible1 == 80 and varible2 == 100:
   print "something"

if varible1 == anything and varible2 == 230:
   print "something"
```

I don't know if my pesudo code makes any sense but that's the just of it.

Comment: Can you spec what is valid input, that is what are valid values for arguments 1 and 2?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your objective properly, you may want to write it like this:

```
possible_values = (1, 2, 3, 4) # put the acceptable values of arguments here

if (sys.argv[1] in possible_values and sys.argv[2] in possible_values):
  print("filtering both")
elif (sys.argv[1] in possible_values or sys.argv[2] in possible_values):
  print("filtering half")
else:
  print("nofilter")
```

If that's not what you want to do, please explain more.

Comment: This would work, there's 3 different variables and some of them have over 1 billion acceptable values. I think i figured it out myself though.

Answer (score 0):

Use dictionary with `frozenset` keys:

```
params_dict = {frozenset(('any',)): 'nofilter',
              frozenset(('1', '2')): 'filter both', 
              frozenset(('any', '1')): 'filter half', 
              frozenset(('any', '2')): 'filter half',
              ....
              }

params_descr = params_dict.get(frozenset(sys.argv[1:3]))

if params_descr is not None:
    print(params_descr)
```